# Woocommerce 2.1.x - How remove View Order in /checkout/order-received/

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a custom payment plugin for Woocomerce.
I need remove the detail of order by "/checkout/order-received/", ie I want remove "Order Details", "Customer details" and "Billing Address".

I had put in my plugin:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table' );
```

but it doesn't work. I've also put in INI , but it still doesn't work.

```
function gowc_process_init() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table' );
}
add_action('init', 'gowc_process_init');
```

Could you help me with this topic, please?
PD: Remember that is a plugin, don't is a theme.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10 );
```